# Cannot use the Session variable

Tags: asp.net

after many research in Google, i didn't found the solution to my problem.

When i want to make enter value to the Session variable, all is ok :

```
Session["idResult"] = youthID;
```

but when i want to get the value with the line code :

```
youthID = (int)Session["idResult"];
```

i get the error :
*Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the `<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules>` section in the application configuration.*

i tried to add in the web.config : 
 *EnableSessionState="True"*

and also :

```
<httpModules><add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>     </httpModules>
<pages enableSessionState="true"/>
```

and many other possibilities but it's doesn't work

my default web.config is :

```
> <?xml version="1.0"?> <!--   For more information on how to configure
> your ASP.NET application, please visit  
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433   --> <configuration>  
> <system.web>
>     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
>     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>   </system.web> </configuration>
```

Comment: Full web.config please, **** out any passwords/server names etc.

Comment: <sessionState mode="InProc"> did you try this tag inside <system.web>?

Comment: In case you are not using: InProc, Make sure that ASP.NET Session State Manager Service  is running.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the session from?

Comment: Few things in web.config are configured incorrectly. As Ryan McDonought is stated, we need to see full web.config except credentials.

Comment: My web.config is :

> <?xml version="1.0"?> <!--   For more information on how to configure
> your ASP.NET application, please visit  
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433   --> <configuration>  
> <system.web>
>     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
>     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>   </system.web> </configuration>

**user1848739** : i tried and its not the solution. thanks

**hanlet** : i try to access the Session from aspx page.

Comment: Update your question with that information.

Comment: i updated my question. Someone knows ?